# php echo html element in samp line

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i use bootstrap in my from control but my input and button not in same line

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" id="title-meaning">Meaning:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8" id="input-mean">

                    <?php
foreach ($words as $row) {
    $word_tmp = $row['meaning'];
}
$meaningarray = explode("/", $word_tmp);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($meaningarray); $i++) {
    echo '<input class="form-control" value="' . htmlspecialchars($meaningarray[$i]) . '" type="text" name="meaning[]" id="meaning">';
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo '<button class="add_field_button" id="btn-add">
                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" id="glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        </button>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}

?>

                </div>
            </div>
```

am try to css button float left ,but not change

how can i do ??

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this. Post the rendered HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the label and form to be inline then change your html to the below code ( I have assumed that form-group is the bootstrap form-group class )

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want the output to look like and you are using bootstrap right?